# Terraform: How to use multiple locals and Variables inside "for_each"

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I have a terraform template that creates multiple EC2 instances.
I then create a few Elastic Network interfaces in the AWS console and added them as locals in the terraform template.
Now, I want to map the appropriate ENI to the instance hence I added locals and variables as below.

```
locals {
  instance_ami = {
    A  = "ami-11111"
    B = "ami-22222"
    C  = "ami-33333"
    D   = "ami-4444"
  }
}

variable "instance_eni" {
  description = "Pre created Network Interfaces"
  default = [
    {
      name = "A"
      id   = "eni-0a15890a6f567f487"
    },
    {
      name = "B"
      id   = "eni-089a68a526af5775b"
    },
    {
      name = "C"
      id   = "eni-09ec8ad891c8e9d91"
    },
    {
      name = "D"
      id   = "eni-0fd5ca23d3af654a9"
    }
  ]
}


resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  for_each = local.instance_ami

  ami           = each.value
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  key_name      = var.keypair

  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = true
    volume_size           = 80
    volume_type           = "gp2"
  }


  dynamic "network_interface" {
    for_each = [for eni in var.instance_eni : {
      eni_id = eni.id
    }]

    content {
      device_index          = 0
      network_interface_id  = network_interface.value.eni_id
      delete_on_termination = false
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting below error:

> Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidParameterValue: Each network interface requires a 
>           unique device index.
>           status code: 400, request id: 4a482753-bddc-4fc3-90f4-2f1c5e2472c7

I think terraform is tyring to attach all 4 ENI's to single instance only.
What should be done to attach ENI's to an individual instance?

Answer (score 4):

The configuration you shared in your question is asking Terraform to manage four instances, each of which has four network interfaces associated with it. That's problematic in two different ways:

- All four of the network interfaces on each instance are configured with the same `device_index`, which is invalid and is what the error message here is reporting.
- Even if you were to fix that, it would then try to attach the same four network interfaces to four different EC2 instances, which is invalid: each network interface can be attached to only one instance at a time.

To address that and get the behavior you wanted, you only need one `network_interface` block, whose content is different for each of the instances:

```
locals {
  instance_ami = {
    A = "ami-11111"
    B = "ami-22222"
    C = "ami-33333"
    D = "ami-4444"
  }
}

variable "instance_eni" {
  description = "Pre created Network Interfaces"
  default = [
    {
      name = "A"
      id   = "eni-0a15890a6f567f487"
    },
    {
      name = "B"
      id   = "eni-089a68a526af5775b"
    },
    {
      name = "C"
      id   = "eni-09ec8ad891c8e9d91"
    },
    {
      name = "D"
      id   = "eni-0fd5ca23d3af654a9"
    }
  ]
}

locals {
  # This expression is transforming the instance_eni
  # value into a more convenient shape: a map from
  # instance key to network interface id. You could
  # also choose to just change directly the
  # definition of variable "instance_eni" to already
  # be such a map, but I did it this way to preserve
  # your module interface as given.
  instance_network_interfaces = {
    for ni in var.instance_eni : ni.name => ni.id
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  for_each = local.instance_ami

  ami           = each.value
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  key_name      = var.keypair

  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = true
    volume_size           = 80
    volume_type           = "gp2"
  }

  network_interface {
    device_index          = 0
    network_interface_id  = local.instance_network_interfaces[each.key]
    delete_on_termination = false
  }
}
```

Now each instance has only *one* network interface, with each one attaching to the corresponding ENI ID given in your input variable. Referring to `each.key` and `each.value` is how we can create differences between each of the instances declared when using resource `for_each`; we don't need any other repetition constructs inside unless we want to create nested repetitions, like having a dynamic number of network interfaces for each instance.

Comment: Hi Martin, getting below error with the above configuration.

"Error: Invalid index

    network_interface_id  = local.instance_network_interfaces[each.key]
    |----------------
    | each.key is "A"
    | local.instance_network_interfaces is object with 4 attributes

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value."

However, I am able to achieve the goal with:
network_interface_id = lookup(var.instance_eni, each.key)

Comment: For the above, I had updated the **instance_eni** variable as below.

variable "instance_eni" {
  default = {
    A  = "eni-0a15890a6f567f487"
    B = "eni-089a68a526af5775b"
    C  = "eni-09ec8ad891c8e9d91"
    D   = "eni-0fd5ca23d3af654a9"
  }
}